# how can I ask peoples' opinion on something?

Tags: discussion, questions, opinion-based

I've gotten several downvotes and questions put on hold for asking questions that were deemed to be overly opion-based.

The thing is, I think opinions are incredibly valuable.  Especially in terms of determining which tool to use for a given task, or to determine if a process is generally thought to be a good idea or bad idea.

For evaluating new technologies or general approaches, there is often no hard data to analyze.

So, if I truly want to ask an opinion-based question about software development, what is the forum (or technique) that I can or should use?

Comment: you go in the chat, or you go on other forums/sites. We should not be the be all end all of all questions

Comment: regardless of how valuable the answers would be, that simply isn't allowed on SO sites, and SE sites in general(see individual site help areas though, there may be exceptions.) You'll have to find some other forum, or use chat.

Comment: You can try the chatrooms. But depending on which rooms and how you approach them, you may or may not get a useful answer.

Comment: It's allowed sometimes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493111/what-is-a-simple-and-reliable-c-library-for-working-with-excel-files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your deleted question had specific issues; you could have fixed these and had a pretty good question. [Here's the question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253298/selenium-parallel-automations-same-vs-different-threads-single-machine-vs):

> Is it considered a good/reasonable idea to run parallel automation
>   code in different webdrivers in the same thread? on the same machine?
>
> or, is it a much better idea to use selenium grid for parallel
>   automation, and why?
>
> i'm interested in specific experience & evidence on this. or
>   helpful/relevant references regarding when you can/should run parallel
>   tests NOT using grid.
>
> i'm also interested in the implications for test result output
>   (testng, junit) regarding different approaches to parallel browser
>   automation

Here are the issues with your question:

1. You don't tell us what problem you're having that the answer to this would solve.  It's like asking "What's better for manufacturing, plastic or metal?"

The answer is, of course, *it depends on your use case*.

2. Why would an answer to this matter to you? This is a different spin on the above issue; but if your answer is solely "curiosity", we need more to go on. Curiosity centered questions are extremely hard to do well; so unless you're a stellar writer (or you've hit on something that a lot of people love), it probably won't work in your favor.
3. Give us details that are relevant to your situation.  Tell us what 'good/reasonable' mean to you. Are you running in the cloud? On your own hardware? Is processing time really a consideration for whatever reason? Do you need your tests to run faster? Run on less boxes? What is it you need from us?

If you solve these issues, your question could be a good question; but you have to solve these issues first.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a small list (not in any particular order):

1. Try a Stack Overflow chatroom.
2. Ask on Reddit; programming, learnprogramming, and cscareerquestions are all good.
3. Find a programming forum; many communities might have their own dedicated forums.
4. Try a mailing list.
5. Logon to Freenode and a relevant chatroom.
6. Talk to friends and co-workers who program.

**0. Google it, or look to blogs that are popular in the field.**

Comment: "Google it" should be at the top of the list.

Comment: ..or just ask on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493111/what-is-a-simple-and-reliable-c-library-for-working-with-excel-files

Comment: @MartinJames inb4 it gets closed. :)

Comment: @MartinJames Quite honestly, if that question were asked right now, I think it would get downvoted and closed because it's "too subjective." :(

Comment: Why is (6) not on the top? In theory your co-workers have much better knowledge about your problem domain.

Comment: @Mysticial  "Google it" is just about the least helpful suggestion anyone could ever offer for anything.  Right after "just think about it" and "well, what do you think."

Comment: @stuart I disagree. The quality of the questions on SO suggests that there's infinitely many people who don't know how to "Google it". What's obvious to us may not be obvious to others.

Comment: @Mysticial could you or anyone point me to some reference that would help me understand the drawbacks of people asking obvious or opinion-based questions on SO?  In my experience, the existence of questions of both types on SO is, often, what has made my googling effective.

Comment: @stuart http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/169611

Answer (score 7):

Those questions are out of scope on the network.  You'll need to find another place, other than Stack Exchange, to ask your questions.